# ImportError cannot import name _common(Python 3.4)

Tags: python, importerror, psutil

I am using Python 3.4 and I just installed psutil. When I import this module using

```
import psutil
```

in the shell I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import psutil
  File "F:\Python34\lib\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from . import _common
ImportError: cannot import name '_common'
```

I have found multiple post about this kind of error, but they were all about an error with a library they made themself so I'm wondering how to fix this then as i just downloaded this and didn't change anything myself.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem too, you shouldn't set your source file in the same path with the library, change the path of the source file, hope can help you.

Comment: Can you clarify further using an example?